# Adding URDF file for VLP-16 into Gazebo

Tags: simulation, ros

I want to simulate an algorithm we wrote in Gazebo. The base robot I am using is the clearpath Husky. And, I need to put a Velodyne VLP-16 Lidar on it to extract the point clouds. The way I am going about it is trying to make my own custom world and launching the Husky launch file which spawns the Husky in a custom world. I just want to know what would be the best way to put the lidar on top of the husky? Can I just modify the world file? Or will I need to change the clearpath file? I downloaded the velodyne_simulator package from Velodyne and it comes with a VLP-16.urdf.xacro. Is there anyway I can use that? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Husky allows for additional accessories to be added via the *husky.urdf.xacro* file indicated by this line of code in the file `<xacro:include filename="$(arg urdf_extras)" />`

The file can be located here https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/kinetic-devel/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro

The final step is to add these lines of VLP-16 code to`/path/to/my/file.urdf`:

```
  <VLP-16 parent="base_link" name="velodyne" topic="/velodyne_points">
      <!-- The 0.2 will most likely have to be adjusted to fit -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </VLP-16>
```

Now the Husky can be launched with the VLP-16 in Gazebo.

`roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch urdf_extras=/path/to/my/file.urdf`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @mastash3ff is mostly correct except there are few things missing. As per the latest husky package you can bring up velodyne VLP-16 or say any model by setting "HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS" environment variable to the urdf file you want to include.

```
export HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS=/path/to/vlp.urdf
```

In my case vlp.urdf looked like this. You can also follow the same pattern

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="example">
 <xacro:include filename="$(find velodyne_description)/urdf/VLP-16.urdf.xacro"/>
  <VLP-16 parent="top_plate_link" name="velodyne" topic="/velodyne_points" hz="10" samples="440">
    <origin xyz="0.2206 0.0 0.00635" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </VLP-16>
</robot>
```

Hope this helps.